# Can I access variables from another file?

Tags: javascript, scope

Is it possible to use a variable in a file called `first.js` inside another file called `second.js`?

`first.js` contains a variable called `colorcodes`.

Comment: @Roki: For example, you could be loading data from another website, while the script to process them is on your site: `<script src="http://datasource.example.net/first.js"></script><script src="second.js"></script>`

Comment: the datasource site don't have a callback?

what i mean:
download second.js
contains:
...
function secondscriptFn(o) {
//do something /w data;
}
...
download http://datasource.example.net/first.js?callback=secondscriptFn
then first contain:
secondscriptFn({back:"#fff",front:"#888",side:"#369"});

more controllable and robust than global scope versions, because you can control the first.js scope...

Comment: Just as a note if you are using jQuery and you are trying to do this. You need to make sure that you don't put the variable that you trying to access from the first file in the '$(document).ready()' function; otherwise it won't load properly, at least from my experience.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

As Fermin said, a variable in the global scope should be accessible to all scripts loaded after it is declared. You could also use a property of `window` or (in the global scope) `this` to get the same effect.

```js
// first.js
var colorCodes = {
  back  : "#fff",
  front : "#888",
  side  : "#369"
};
```

... in another file ...

```js
// second.js
alert(colorCodes.back); // alerts `#fff`
```

... in your html file ...

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="first.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
```

Comment: In a browser, `window` *is* the global scope - so window.colorCodes and the (global) object colorCodes is the same object.

Comment: True... the reason I mention it is for cases where you need to set a global variable from a non-global scope.

Comment: what about html? in html I have: `<script>var variable1 = true;</script>
<script src="first.js"></script>` will first.js see that variable? I tested it in Google Chrome extension and it didn't work

Comment: @user25, I have the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Comment: If you are using eslint, you can add `/* global colorCodes */` on the line above to prevent "...is not defined" error message

Comment: @user25 and Mercury code in first.js can access variables defined at the global scope level in HTML from within the script tag. This may not be the case for Google Chrome extensions which is out of the boundaries of this SO question.

Comment: This is an outdated answer. Please accept my answer below that uses ES6 export/import syntax, which is mostly the standard now.

Comment: Just a littel hint on the first block on this answer. As you can see it has been written with var. This is very important since var is adding the colorCodes to the global scope. If you do use let, it won't be adding colorCodes  to the global scope, therefore you won't be able to use in another file.

Answer (score 97):

You can export the variable from first file using **export**.

```
//first.js
const colorCode = {
    black: "#000",
    white: "#fff"
};
export { colorCode };
```

Then, import the variable in second file using **import**.

```
//second.js
import { colorCode } from './first.js'
```

[export - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: `const` in the example and talking about `variable` - am I missing something? If I do this and use a variable `var` and try to assign then at least in a Chrome extension it complains with "Cannot set property XXX of #<Object> which has only a getter". If this can only be done with `const`/read-only, then this is a highly misleading answer.

Comment: `const` is a type of a variable. `var` is also a type of a variable. They're two different kinds of variables and have different characteristics. The answer is not misleading, you're just using the wrong kind of variable for your use case.
This cannot be done with const - they're immutable after initialization.
You can learn about the different variable declarations here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements#declarations

Comment: This gives me the error: `An export declaration can only be used at the top level of a module.`

Answer (score 19):

Using Node.js you can export the variable via module.

```
//first.js
const colorCode = {
    black: "#000",
    white: "#fff"
};
module.exports = { colorCode };
```

Then, import the module/variable in second file using require.

```
//second.js
const { colorCode } = require('./first.js')
```

You can use the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) aproach from ES6 using Webpack/Babel, but in Node.js you need to [enable a flag, and uses the .mjs extension.](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

Comment: does it have to be a const in order to export it?

Comment: In Node.js, this is not longer the case. You can simply add ``type: module`` in the package.json file to use import / export natively.

Answer (score 16):

This should work - define a global variable in firstfile and access it from secondfile:

```
<script src="/firstfile.js"></script>
<script src="/secondfile.js"></script>
```

firstfile.js:

```
var colors = {
   text:'#000000',
   background:'#aaaaaa',
   something_else:'blue'
};
```

secondfile.js:

```
do_something_with(colors.background);
```

Note that the order in which you load the script files is significant for some browsers (IE6 for sure, maybe others)

Comment: You may need to attach that variable to the object like: this.colors = colors. If its an object rather than an enum, you can make a function to just return the value. this.getTextColor = function() { return colors.text; };

Comment: how would you update a variable from a loaded page? <script type="text/javascript">colors.background="new col"; </script> doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 16):

I did like the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244411/4251431) said, but it didn't work for me at first because I was declaring these variables inside jQuery `$( document ).ready()`.

So make sure you declare your variables inside the `<script>` tag not somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

I came across [amplify.js](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/). It's really simple to use. To store a value, let's call it "myValue", you do:

```
amplify.store("myKey", "myValue")
```

And to access it, you do

```
amplify.store("myKey")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you store your colorcodes in a global variable you should be able to access it from either javascript file.

Answer (score 2):

I may be doing this a little differently. I'm not sure why I use this syntax, copied it from some book a long time ago. But each of my js files defines a variable. The first file, for no reason at all, is called R:

```
    var R = 
    { 
        somevar: 0,
        othervar: -1,

        init: function() {
          ...
        } // end init function

        somefunction: function(somearg) {
          ...
        }  // end somefunction

        ...

    }; // end variable R definition


    $( window ).load(function() {
       R.init();
    })
```

And then if I have a big piece of code that I want to segregate, I put it in a separate file and a different variable name, but I can still reference the R variables and functions. I called the new one TD for no good reason at all:

```
    var TD = 
    { 
        xvar: 0,
        yvar: -1,

        init: function() {
           ...
        } // end init function

        sepfunction: function() {
           ...
           R.somefunction(xvar);
           ...
        }  // end somefunction

        ...

    }; // end variable TD definition


    $( window ).load(function() {
       TD.init();
    })
```

You can see that where in the TD 'sepfunction' I call the R.somefunction.
I realize this doesn't give any runtime efficiencies because both scripts to need to load, but it does help me keep my code organized.