# How to access variable in other javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose Now I've a HTML file with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/second.js"></script>
```

Both JS contain sets of functions, how can I access second.js from first.js?

Comment: are you locating them at the head?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script>` elements are executed in order. You can't access things defined in second.js while first.js is being first executed, but if you define a function in first.js and set it up so that it's called after second.js has been loaded it will see anything defined in second.js. A DOM ready or a "load" event might be a start.

Comment: I put them in the head, and do I have to specify something like global? Or  "var x,y" is fine?

Comment: `var`s in the global scope (outside any functions) are global.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can act like this. Make it in Order.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/second.js"></script>
<script>
    //call the function at first.js which will access second.js
    exampleFirstJSFunc();
</script>
```