# How can I move a variable from javascript to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have A, B html and A, B javascript files.

And, How can I move global variable used in A JavaScript directly to B Javascript?

example A javascript)

```
var pos;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
$(document).on('click', '#length_' + i, function() {
  pos = $(this).attr('id');
  });
}
```

pos (global variable) -> B javascript ?

I'm so sorry, I can't english well...

Comment: Are all the files attached to the same html?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I access variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file)

Comment: @D-reaper No, another htmls. (A.html, B.html)

Comment: @noobcode Thank you!

Comment: @prasad Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to access `var pos` in your other JS file.
To achieve this you need to load your A.js which contains global variable file first
eg.

```
<script src="a.js" />
<script src="b.js" />
```

this way you can access global variable defined in a, in b.