# If statement Javascript using variable from other file

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my javascript code.

numbercars.js

```
var cars = {
chan1:'',
number:'2';}
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="numbercars.js"></script>
    <script>
    var numbercars = cars.number;

    if (numbercars =<9){
    //My action
    }
    else{
    //My second action
    } 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       HTML CONTENT
    </body>
</html>
```

But this statement didn't work, all time, it's else.

Can you, if you can, tell me where is my error, i didn't understand.

Thank you

Comment: first file is numbercar.js and second numbercars.js is that correct? try change the cars name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I access variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file)

Comment: @OrryVandermeulen first file numbercars.js who I declare the number of Cars. The second file is index.html who I need to make a statement from the number of cars. Exemple : if number >2, I can do an action, if <2, I can't do nothing

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(cars)` in your second `script` tag? It seems to me that you are not loading the script properly. Are the files in the same directory?

Answer (score 1):

## You have two issues

A semi-colon in your `cars` object.  Remove it.

```
var cars = {
    chan1:'',
    number:'2';
}
              ^
```

You're using an invalid combination of operators to compare numbers.  Change to `numbercars <= 9`

```
if (numbercars =< 9){
               ^
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have moved a semi colon and I change my operator, that's not work again

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon and quotation marks for integers.

```
var cars = {
  chan1:'',
  number: 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but that not change :)