# How to pass/use req.params to front-end js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to send req.params to the front end and use it with various js functions, but I do not know how to access it on the client side with js.

Specifically, I am trying to grab the `req.param` called `namespace` that the user inputs using

```
app.get('/:namespace', function(req,res){
  res.render('chatLayout', { title: 'Welcome to the ' + 
  req.params.namespace +" room!"}), {namespace: req.params.namespace };

});
```

and then set a variable named `room` in the client side js file likes this:
`var room= io.connect('http://localhost:3000/' +namespace);`

However, since I do not know how to make the `req.params.namespace` accessible to the client side js file, namespace is undefined.

Note: I am using pug as my templating language

I have tried a few things.

1. Trying to call `req.params.namespace` or `namespace`, from within the client side js file, but both throw an error saying that they are not defined
2. Creating a global variable in the pug file using a script tag before calling the js file and setting `var a=namespace` or `var a=req.params.namespace`, but this doesn't seem to make the variable accessible to the js file. It seems like it should work like in this question [Can I access variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file) , so maybe this method might work but I am just not doing it correctly

Backend

```
    var express= require('express');
    var socket= require('socket.io');

    //App setup
    var app= express();
    app.set('view engine', 'pug');
    var server= app.listen(3000, function(){
    });

   //Static files
    app.get('/:namespace', function(req,res){
      res.render('chatLayout', { title: 'Welcome to the ' + 
    req.params.namespace +" room!"}), {namespace: req.params.namespace };

    });
```

Client side js

```
   var room= io.connect('http://localhost:3000/' +namespace);
```

Pug file

```
    doctype html
    html(lang='en')
      head
        title= title
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        <script 
    src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js'> 
   </script>
    <script src="/gameChat.js"></script>
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/style.css')
  body
   <h1>#{title} </h1>
   <div id= "chat">
        <div id= "chat-window">
            <div id= "output"></div>
            <div id= "feedback"></div>
        </div>
        <form id ="form">
            <input id= "handle" type= "text" placeholder="Handle"/>
            <input id= "message" type = "text" placeholder="Message"/>
            <button id= "send">Send</button>
        </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send variable to 2nd param of `res.render`:

```
app.get('/:namespace', function(req, res) {
    res.render('chatLayout', {
        title: 'Welcome to the ' + req.params.namespace + " room!",
        namespace: req.params.namespace
    });

});
```

and call `namespace` from template

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `namespace` variable in the head tag, before you use it (before `<script src="/gameChat.js"></script>` line).

Just use Pug syntax:

```
script.
  loginName="#{namespace}";
```

Complete template code:

```
doctype html
    html(lang='en')
      head
        title= title
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')

        <script  src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js'></script>
        script.
          var namespace="#{namespace}";

        <script src="/gameChat.js"></script>
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/style.css')
  body

<h1>#{title} </h1>
<div id= "chat">
    <div id= "chat-window">
        <div id= "output"></div>
        <div id= "feedback"></div>
    </div>
    <form id ="form">
        <input id= "handle" type= "text" placeholder="Handle"/>
        <input id= "message" type = "text" placeholder="Message"/>
        <button id= "send">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and in your server side, you have to render `chatLayout` template with an object what includes `namespace` data:

```
app.get("/:namespace", function(req, res) {
  res.render("chatLayout", {
    title: "Welcome to the " + req.params.namespace + " room!",
    namespace: req.params.namespace
  });
});
```