# How to link JavaScript files to use arrays from other files

Tags: javascript

I am working on `orders.js` but I need arrays from `products/products.js`  and from `users/users.js`, How could I get access to those files to work on the actual file? I am a beginner with JavaScript and I don't know well how I have to link those files.

I am not using any framework  or library, Vanilla Java Scrip only

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: `$.getJSON('filepath')` search for it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON file into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-server-memory)

Comment: There are different ways.. you can create a service.js file and use that as a bridge between both files. If you are using a framework look out for the available pattern in that. Or set the details required to window object and they will be accessible in all js files

Comment: Just use `<script src='yourPage.js'></script>`s in your `<head>`. Make sure you use `addEventListener('load', ()=>{ /* other script is accessible */ });`

Comment: Hello I want to use an array called users  and another one called products  in orders/ordes.js

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Can I access variables from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244411/12731030)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit more of a complicated question than it might at first seem. JavaScript is a language that is used in various environments, and it has a number of module systems.

From the picture you posted it seems like you are trying to implement a standard webpage with JS files for each page. In this case you're not able to directly "import" variables from other files, instead you must load them all into the global context that all files are sharing in the browser.

Essentially you should have some `data.js` script that is loaded in the `index.html`. Then you can expose some data such as:

```
var myProducts = ['a', 'b'];
```

Any script loaded after `data.js` will then be able to access `myProducts`.

To further elaborate on JS modules: it is typical to use a packager such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which will pre-compile your pages and JS files and allow you to do what your describing ie. importing modules from other files in your code. However, Webpack can be very complicated to setup, especially for a beginner, I would suggest trying out [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) which should get you up and running really quickly.

Once you have a packager setup then you would be able to import modules from other files like so:

```
# data.js
module.exports = {
  myProducts: ['a', 'b'],
};

# page.js
const { myProducts } = require('path/to/data.js');
```

Note on ES modules:
ParcelJS actually comes with the latest standard (ES modules) pre-configured, so in this setup you would be able to use the following syntax:

```
# data.js
export const myProducts = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

# page.js
import { myProducts } from 'path/to/data.js';
```