# Identify common variables accros multiple scripts

Tags: javascript

How can identify which of the variables are used as Global variables across multiple scripts?

I am trying to solve an error that occors in a web-page that I didn't write.

The web-page imports many different scripts, written in `Vanilla JavaScript`.

Appearently, there are a few common variables that are used accross multiple script files, which is the cause for the problem.

Changing all the types from `let` to `var` - by using 'replace' (cntl+h on vscode in the combined file) - solved the issue.

Seems that the former programmer used something like this -
[Can I access variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file)

Anyway, in order to fix it, I would like to identify which are the common variables and what scripts using them.

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: You can look at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Proxy

Comment: First of, how did you replace let -> var? Can you try and focus on those let, and check how are they used? Since that causes the problem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **LocalStorage** concept.

For an example:

```
let key = 'Item 1';
localStorage.setItem(key, 'Value'); 
localStorage.getItem(key);  //use this syntax any other file it will work.
```

Else

use **require** method:

```
const varName = require('./importYourScript.js')
console.log(varName);
```

If you are using **ECMAScript**:

```
import varName from './importYourScript';
console.log(varName);
```