# JSF custom component, pass data from JSF to Javascript and reverse

Tags: javascript, jsf

I want to **build a custom component** in JSF that could :

1. retrieve a value from its `value` attribute
2. display this value
3. be able to update this value through Javascript (will update bean attribute used in value component attribute)

```
<t:myComponent value="#{myBean.value}" />
```

will display

```
<div>
    <input id="my_input" type="text" value="my_value" />
    <button onclick="update_value(document.getElementById('my_input').value)">update</button>
</div>

<script>
    function update_value(val) {
        // ???
    }
</script>
```

and when we click the button, it will change `myBean.value` by the current content of the input (that user can change obviously).

As I understand, it looks easy to display the value in the component with the `ResponseWriter` but I do not understand how to build Javascript to call the component to change the value of the component.

*example*

```
// myBean.value = "foo"

<t:myComponent value="#{myBean.value}" />

// displays

<div>
    <input id="my_input" type="text" value="foo" />
    <button ...>update</button>
</div>

// user change input content by "bar"

// user click the update button

// myBean.value = "bar" now
```

Comment: Look at the source of PrimeFaces components (or JSF components with ajax). They all have this in them.

Answer (score 0):

### Pass Bean Values to Javascript

There are some ways to do this. I think the most obvious way of doing this is rendering a `script` tag and putting the information in this.

Single Value:

```
writer.write("var value = '" + yourValue + "';");
```

---

Map Values:

```
String s = "var values = {";

for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    s += entry.getKey() + ": '" + entry.getValue() + "',\n";
}

s = s.trim().substring(1, s.length() - 1); // removes last ','

s += "};";

writer.write(s);
```

---

List Values:

```
String s = "var values = [";

for (String value : list) {
    s += "'" + value + "', ";
}

s = s.trim().substring(1, s.length() - 1); // removes last ','

s += "];";

writer.write(s);
```

I would recommend not to put everthing in this script because this would be very much code in the `encode` methods. Rather have the static javascript code in a .js file and just write the dynamic content in the `script` tag. See [how to get variables from other scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file).

---

Another way does not need a `script` tag. This way would call a js method like this:

```
function init(values) {
    // ...
}
```

In the Renderer just call the js method:

```
facesContext.getPartialViewContext().getEvalScripts().add("init(" + yourValue + ");");
```

---

### Pass Javascript values to Server-Side

Just include an input like this:

```
// just a random unique id
String generatedId = context.getClientId(context) + ":utility";

// ...

writer.startElement("input", null);

writer.writeAttribute("id", generatedId, null);
writer.writeAttribute("name", generatedId, null);
writer.writeAttribute("type", "hidden", null);

writer.endElement("input");
```

Then pass the `generatedId`  with the other values to javascript.

---

In Javascript:

```
function setValues(value) {
    // hiddenInputId is the server-side generatedId
    var input = document.getElementId(hiddenInputId);

    input.value = value;
}
```

Then just send an ajax request and get the values in the `decode` method like this:

```
// same id as in the encode methods
String generatedId = context.getClientId(context) + ":utility";

Map<String, String> map = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

String value = map.get(generatedId);

// ...
```

Comment: I think you just missed the most important part of the question which is : **building a custom component**...

Comment: @robinvrd sorry I misread the question and thought of a composite component. I will edit the answer to fit making a UIComponent

Comment: @robinvrd I have edited the question to fit it for use in custom components