# Is there any way to access variables from the second file to the first file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing a situation where I have to access a javascript variable from the second file to the first one. But unfortunately, I don't want to rearrange the script order (Because this is the situation).

In HTML:

```
<body>
  <script src="frist.js"></script>
  <script src="second.js"></script>
</body>
```

In frist.js:

```
console.log(foo); // Got access from second file
```

In second.js:

```
const foo = "Access me" // Trying to access from first.js
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong..Could pls explain more about your requirement...

Comment: Try exporting the second.js file and then import it on the first.js file. Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: I not using any js framework or nodeJS only pure HTML and JS @JakariaRidoy

Comment: @BiswajitBiswas Still, you can do this as JavaScript provides the export and import module. Here is the solution you can take a look [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/export-import-javascript-vkbc8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I access variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file)

Comment: ah, I missed that you are not able to rearrange script order. sorry!

Comment: @DanO Yes it does. Solution link [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/export-import-javascript-vkbc8?file=/src/index2.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript function setTimeout in your first.js file.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert(foo);
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**first.js**

```
import foo from "./second.js";
console.log(foo);
```

**second.js**

```
const foo = "Jakaria";
export default foo;
```

Hope this solves the problem. *And I also provide you the Sandbox link in the comment box above for a hands-on look.*