# JS one reference for all script variables

Tags: javascript

Is there an option to get a reference to the whole script variables?

lets assume this code:

```
const a=n=>n+1,
b={};
let c=3
```

I wonder if I can access all variables by one reference, like this `vars`:

```
vars.b //{}
vars[varName]
```

so that I'll be able to pass it to other sub modules easily instead of creating a manualy associative array with the variables of the script

Comment: as far as i know i dont think you can just simply use something like `vars[varName]` to get all the variables in the whole file

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate all variable you need into object and send the object?

Comment: this should help: [can-i-access-variables-from-another-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only to some limit.

There is `globalThis` variable acting as a container for all top-level variables.
And also in every function `arguments` variable is available holding everything passed to function in the current call.

I'm not aware of anything similar for function-/block-scope variables

Answer (score 0):

I think you can assign those variables to a JSON object and then export the JSON object as follows so that you can reference all the variables in other file.

```js
// scripts.js file

let a = n => n+1;
let b = {};
let c = 3;

module.exports = { a, b, c };
```

```js
// index.js file

const scripts = require('./scripts');

console.log(scripts.a(4));
console.log(scripts.b);
console.log(scripts.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to programatically get access to the [environment record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-internal-slots-of-ecmascript-function-objects) of a given function/scope/closure. To do something like this, the best way would be to define the variables as part of an object or Map in the first place. Instead of

```
const a=n=>n+1,
b={};
let c=3
```

do

```
const theNamespace = {
  a: n=>n+1,
  b: {},
  c: 3
};
```

and pass `theNamespace` around.